# Jump with force Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm wanting my player to jump with a force affecting it's rigidbody. Currently, I have the following code in my `FixedUpdate` loop:

```
else if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) &&( Input.mousePosition.y < Screen.height/3) && isGrounded == true)
{
    Debug.Log ("jump");
    isGrounded = false;
    if(!isGrounded)
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed);

    Debug.Log(isGrounded);
}
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    isGrounded = true;
}
```

When I press my mouse button at the appropriate point on the screen I get all the correct debug information is displayed. But my player doesn't move. The jumpSpeed is set to 100 and I've even tried setting it to 1000 to see if my force was just too low. But nothing. Am I doing something silly here?

Answer (score 0):

A quick question? Why do you have the check of
    if (!isGrounded)
Before you add the force? It will always evaluate to true, since you set it to false right before. Perhaps you meant to do the check outside of the logic checking for the jump input.

Anyway, on to the answer. If you read the docs on [AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) you will see that there is an optional parameter for what type of force this is. The default is 'Force,' and what you want is 'impulse' so change your line to this:

```
Debug.Log ("jump");
isGrounded = false;
rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine, I guess the problem will be in some other piece in your code.